# checking on form validation whether a choice has been clicked (radio button) before allowing user onto the next section

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have a multiple choice questionnaire with five questions on my html page. Each question uses radio buttons for user to select one of five answers. I want to check that the user has selected one of those five radio buttons before allowing them to go to another page. A PHP page sends the answer to my database. If the user misses checking one of the answers, none of the answers go into the database.
I think I'm looking for some java script that will loop through each of the possible five answers to check at the form submit whether the user has checked one radio button before allowing them to proceed to the next page. Thanks for your help.
My html code for just two of the questions looks like this:

```
<tr> <td> Question 1.  </td> 
<td  align="center"> <input type="radio" name="q1" value="0" /></td>
<td  align="center"> <input type="radio" name="q1" value="1" /> </td>
<td  align="center"> <input type="radio" name="q1" value="2" /> </td>
 <td  align="center"> <input type="radio" name="q1" value="3" /> </td>
 <td  align="center"> <input type ="radio" name="q1" value="4" /> </td> 
 </tr>
 <tr> <td> Question 2.  </td>
 <td  align="center"><input type="radio" name="q2" value="0"/></td>
 <td  align="center"> <input type="radio" name="q2" value="1"/> </td>
 <td  align="center"> <input type="radio" name="q2" value="2"/> </td>
 <td  align="center"> <input type="radio" name="q2" value="3"/> </td>
 <td  align="center"> <input type ="radio" name="q2" value= "4"/> </td> </tr>
```

Comment: What JavaScript have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example..And do the changes in your code.....
You can call a js function(using onsubmit()). Like this

```
<form id="ID" method="post" action="servletName" onSubmit="return validateOption()">
<input type=radio name=r1 value="1" >A</input>

<input type=radio name=r1 value="2">B</input>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"><span id="error" style="display:none;"></span>
</form>
```

Your script goes here to validate whether option selected or not,Submission of page is possible only if onsubmit=true ie if validateOption() returns true.

```
<script>
function validateOption()
{
    var group=document.getElementsByName("r1");

     for ( var i = 0; i < group.length; i++)
     { 
         if (group[i].checked) 
             return true;
             }
        // else you can show error message like this
        document.getElementById("error").innerHTML="Please enter your choice";
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks uma_SF I do want to show an error message as you suggest. That means I need an else statement doesn't it? Can you say if the error message needs else before it?

Comment: No need of else..If any of the options are checked.. if (group[i].checked) 
             return true; will return true and if no option is selected it will return false...
Once it return true next statements are not proccessed so no need of else...

Comment: Will do up vote if works and thanks. Will try this tomorrow now, Rosie

Comment: Hello again,Struggling with head cold and not thinking too clearly. I have tried exactly your example, first putting the java into the html page, and secondly as a separate js document. (I'm using the html page I originally had and it was connected to an external js). But I keep getting an error message from the server, "Object not found!
The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error." so I can't tell if your code works or not. I should normally be able to work this out.

Comment: try out some basic simple examples and you will come to kno..Try some sample in w3schools.com...I just gave a rough idea..It might have errors...